# Camera problems in After Effects

Tags: video, after-effects

I have this problem where when I add a camera layer, my composition disappears (but only when the view mode is set to Active Camera). How can I fix it?
[image]
I also have problems zooming in on just a part of the composition. Like from wide view to a specific layer.

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: @JasonConrad I'm on a ASUS ROG laptop if this is what you meant by hardware, and I'm using Adobe After Effects CC.

Comment: I ask because I was switching between renderers (cuda, metal, open cl) in Premiere last night just to see the performance differences, and was having some problems where the screen wouldn't re-draw.  I was thinking your problem might be related to the graphics card.  I don't know enough about it to really know, but was hoping someone here might have some insight along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I was a complete noob ( for I am new with After Effects ). I couldn't see my composition because the blur on the camera was turned to 100% and everything was completely out of focus. Also, I couldn't zoom in on a specific layer because the camera was underneath them. [**This video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Axa38beTBvo) helped me a lot to understand the way camera works in Adobe After Effects, and I wish I had found it earlier because I am dealing with this problem for a while now.
Thank you @JasonConrad for trying to help!